# Gnome 3 old interface

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gnome, gnome-shell

I'm going nuts! I installed the a newer version of Gnome (it's now 3.5.1), but I'm still seeing the old interface. I want the interface with the "activities" button in the left top corner. Now I see it like the picture below. I have ubuntu 12.04. Does anyone have a clue? Of what did I forget to switch on?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a fallback mode for older video cards. Check if your graphics drivers are installed and work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are selecting Gnome Classic from the login screen. You should have some more options in the session menu. Try choosing one of those.